# Java Regex не находит группы

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имею такой паттерн:

```
(?m).*\\bkey\b\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+).*
```

и например, такой текст:

```
key type value
```

При поиске с функцией .find(), вывожу все группы:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
}
```

но здесь он почему-то не выводит 'value', результат:

```
key type value
type
```

в чем может быть дело?

Comment: А вот тут - `key\b` - опечатка? Надо `for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) `

Comment: да, опечатка, ок cпаcибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество групп, возвращаемых `groupCount()`, это количество захватывающих групп в шаблоне + целое совпадение.

```
String s = "key type value";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m).*\\bkey\\b\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while(matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) { // Тут i <= matcher.groupCount()
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

См. [Java-демо](http://ideone.com/24J8Tn).